# vertical-align: top two floated divs within container

Tags: html, css, css-float, position, vertical-alignment

I've tried every combination of `position:` I could think of to align `#blog` and `#sidebar` along their top edges, but nothing I'm doing seems to work. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
#blog-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
#blog {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
    width: 620px;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="blog-container">
    <div id="blog">
        <content>
    </div><!-- end blog -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <content>
    </div><!-- end sidebar -->
</div><!-- end blog-container -->
```

[image: current]

Comment: actually they align well: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/S6S8M/ ... in which browser are you experiencing this problem?

Comment: odd, I'm using Firefox 15.0.1. I've attached an image of what I'm currently seeing. My goal is to have the teal social buttons align with the top of the wooden Post Title box.

Comment: Why are you using relative positioning here?

Comment: @Diodeus After reading through several other posts here that seemed to be a popular method of achieving the vertical alignment. Obviously it's not working in this case, so I'm open to whatever suggestion you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the sidebar first (in the HTML) and float it right, then the blog and float it left.

```
<div id="blog-container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <content/>
    </div><!-- end sidebar -->
    <div id="blog">
        <content/>
    </div><!-- end blog -->
</div><!-- end blog-container -->
```

Comment: This was one of the solutions I tried initially, no visible changes were made despite swapping the `<div>` placement.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site where you are having the problem?

Comment: The site isn't live quite yet, but here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BwPD/)

Comment: You need to remove the `padding-top: 200px` from the .social class - your sidebar is actually at the top, it is just being padded. When having spacing issues like this I will often put an arbitrary border around the containers in question to see where their borders are - similarly you can right click and "inspect element" in Chrome, and when you hover over the tag in the inspector it will highlight the container in blue, padding in green, and margins in orange.

Comment: oh, you are absolutely correct. i was using the same `.social` for both the sidebar and the footer- the padding is essential in the footer, obviously not so in the sidebar. changing the sidebar element to `.blog-social` remedied that. sorry for having overlooked such a small thing, but thanks for your answer!